# PNG image required to be converted from JSON and email

Tags: php, html, json, image

So I have used a signature pad from another source and the pad works fine. When I submit the form, it saves the image as JSON code and this is useful as I need to store it within a database as well. However upon submission, I need to convert the code to png and email the image. This is the code I use to convert the code to image, $output2 is the JSON code from the signature capture, signature-to-image.php is the file actually converting the image:

```
require_once 'signature-to-image.php';
$img = sigJsonToImage($output2);
// Save to file
imagepng($img);
// Destroy the image in memory when complete - I destroy the image at the very end of the PHP file
```

This code converts the code fine as I have tested it opening a header with just $img in it and the image appears fine.

However when I try to add the png image to the body of the email, it just shows up as Resource id#7. I use the line of code below to send the image:

```
$email_message .= "Signature: ".clean_string($img)."\n";
```

I am assuming I need to either embed the image within the body of the email (which I am unfamiliar with) or I need to send the image as an attachment (which I am also unfamiliar with). Am I correct in thinking this? which option is the better choice or is there a better alternative?

So I write in the signature pad, it captures the signature and saves the image in JSON (as far as I am aware, I have zero experience using JSON) This is an example of the output I would receive: 
    [{"lx":46,"ly":49,"mx":46,"my":48},{"lx":46,"ly":48,"mx":46,"my":49},{"lx":46,"ly":51,"mx":46,"my":48},{"lx":46,"ly":55,"mx":46,"my":51},{"lx":46,"ly":62,"mx":46,"my":55},{"lx":47,"ly":69,"mx":46,"my":62},{"lx":52,"ly":94,"mx":47,"my":69},{"lx":54,"ly":105,"mx":52,"my":94},{"lx":56,"ly":114,"mx":54,"my":105},{"lx":58,"ly":126,"mx":56,"my":114},{"lx":59,"ly":133,"mx":58,"my":126},{"lx":60,"ly":136,"mx":59,"my":133},{"lx":60,"ly":140,"mx":60,"my":136},{"lx":88,"ly":25,"mx":88,"my":24},{"lx":88,"ly":24,"mx":88,"my":25},{"lx":88,"ly":28,"mx":88,"my":24},{"lx":89,"ly":33,"mx":88,"my":28},{"lx":90,"ly":39,"mx":89,"my":33},{"lx":91,"ly":43,"mx":90,"my":39},{"lx":93,"ly":60,"mx":91,"my":43},{"lx":94,"ly":69,"mx":93,"my":60},{"lx":96,"ly":79,"mx":94,"my":69},{"lx":98,"ly":94,"mx":96,"my":79},{"lx":99,"ly":102,"mx":98,"my":94},{"lx":100,"ly":114,"mx":99,"my":102},{"lx":100,"ly":117,"mx":100,"my":114},{"lx":100,"ly":118,"mx":100,"my":117},{"lx":100,"ly":120,"mx":100,"my":118},{"lx":28,"ly":116,"mx":28,"my":115},{"lx":28,"ly":115,"mx":28,"my":116},{"lx":28,"ly":114,"mx":28,"my":115},{"lx":30,"ly":113,"mx":28,"my":114},{"lx":32,"ly":112,"mx":30,"my":113},{"lx":36,"ly":110,"mx":32,"my":112},{"lx":57,"ly":104,"mx":36,"my":110},{"lx":67,"ly":100,"mx":57,"my":104},{"lx":91,"ly":92,"mx":67,"my":100},{"lx":121,"ly":75,"mx":91,"my":92},{"lx":127,"ly":72,"mx":121,"my":75},{"lx":129,"ly":72,"mx":127,"my":72},{"lx":130,"ly":72,"mx":129,"my":72},{"lx":130,"ly":73,"mx":130,"my":72},{"lx":196,"ly":48,"mx":196,"my":47},{"lx":196,"ly":47,"mx":196,"my":48},{"lx":198,"ly":45,"mx":196,"my":47},{"lx":200,"ly":43,"mx":198,"my":45},{"lx":204,"ly":42,"mx":200,"my":43},{"lx":209,"ly":41,"mx":204,"my":42},{"lx":219,"ly":40,"mx":209,"my":41},{"lx":232,"ly":39,"mx":219,"my":40},{"lx":238,"ly":39,"mx":232,"my":39},{"lx":244,"ly":39,"mx":238,"my":39},{"lx":257,"ly":38,"mx":244,"my":39},{"lx":261,"ly":38,"mx":257,"my":38},{"lx":263,"ly":38,"mx":261,"my":38},{"lx":223,"ly":42,"mx":223,"my":41},{"lx":223,"ly":41,"mx":223,"my":42},{"lx":223,"ly":44,"mx":223,"my":41},{"lx":223,"ly":45,"mx":223,"my":44},{"lx":223,"ly":50,"mx":223,"my":45},{"lx":223,"ly":52,"mx":223,"my":50},{"lx":223,"ly":56,"mx":223,"my":52},{"lx":223,"ly":75,"mx":223,"my":56},{"lx":223,"ly":84,"mx":223,"my":75},{"lx":223,"ly":91,"mx":223,"my":84},{"lx":223,"ly":110,"mx":223,"my":91},{"lx":223,"ly":119,"mx":223,"my":110},{"lx":223,"ly":123,"mx":223,"my":119},{"lx":223,"ly":127,"mx":223,"my":123},{"lx":222,"ly":129,"mx":223,"my":127},{"lx":221,"ly":129,"mx":222,"my":129},{"lx":219,"ly":130,"mx":221,"my":129},{"lx":217,"ly":130,"mx":219,"my":130},{"lx":211,"ly":131,"mx":217,"my":130},{"lx":201,"ly":131,"mx":211,"my":131},{"lx":192,"ly":132,"mx":201,"my":131},{"lx":181,"ly":132,"mx":192,"my":132},{"lx":177,"ly":132,"mx":181,"my":132},{"lx":173,"ly":132,"mx":177,"my":132},{"lx":163,"ly":132,"mx":173,"my":132},{"lx":161,"ly":132,"mx":163,"my":132},{"lx":159,"ly":132,"mx":161,"my":132},{"lx":161,"ly":132,"mx":159,"my":132},{"lx":166,"ly":131,"mx":161,"my":132},{"lx":172,"ly":130,"mx":166,"my":131},{"lx":176,"ly":130,"mx":172,"my":130},{"lx":192,"ly":130,"mx":176,"my":130},{"lx":203,"ly":130,"mx":192,"my":130},{"lx":211,"ly":130,"mx":203,"my":130},{"lx":219,"ly":130,"mx":211,"my":130},{"lx":222,"ly":130,"mx":219,"my":130},{"lx":228,"ly":130,"mx":222,"my":130},{"lx":232,"ly":130,"mx":228,"my":130},{"lx":235,"ly":130,"mx":232,"my":130},{"lx":240,"ly":130,"mx":235,"my":130},{"lx":241,"ly":130,"mx":240,"my":130},{"lx":242,"ly":130,"mx":241,"my":130},{"lx":243,"ly":130,"mx":242,"my":130},{"lx":246,"ly":130,"mx":243,"my":130},{"lx":250,"ly":129,"mx":246,"my":130},{"lx":261,"ly":128,"mx":250,"my":129},{"lx":265,"ly":128,"mx":261,"my":128},{"lx":267,"ly":127,"mx":265,"my":128},{"lx":269,"ly":127,"mx":267,"my":127}]

Comment: **it saves the image as JSON code**

What does this mean?

Comment: I have updated the question @alistaircol